# Any way to get Prime Pantry products in the Amazon PAAPI

Tags: api, amazon-product-api

I am currently using the PAAPI to get products for manufacturers, but now need to get Prime Pantry items and I'm not sure of a way to do this or if its possible.

Using the following Response group gets all the products:

```
string responseGroup = "Large";
```

We have been told by Amazon that it is possible to get Prime Pantry items using the PAAPI and an example they gave us was using response group:

```
responseGroup = "Images,ItemAttributes,Offers";
```

However this just seems to get fewer items and not prime pantry.

I have also tried using the following:

```
 responseGroup = "IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping ";
 responseGroup = "IsEligibleForPrime";
```

Here is an example of a product that I would like to be getting:

[http://www.amazon.com/Barilla-Pasta-Rotini-16-Ounce/dp/B00IB1D0IO/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1446627950&sr=8-3&keywords=Barilla+Pasta%2C+Rotini%2C+16+Ounce](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00IB1D0IO)

Any help would be greatly appreciated I have searched through:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/CHAP_ApiReference.html

But haven t found anything that helps me yet.

Answer (score 0):

I  don't know if you still need a solution... but i found one.
It's not officially documented but you can use Pantry as SearchIndex and then search Amazon Pantry:

unsigned url:
http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&Operation=ItemSearch&SubscriptionId=XXXXXXXXXXXX&AssociateTag=XXXXXXXXXXXX&SearchIndex=Appliances&ResponseGroup=Large&Keywords=Barilla